# how to check existing record in sqlite?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

hai how to check the already existing records in sqlite3. I want to insert the parsed record from feed. it works but the issue is when i run the application twice record also stored in database twice. please give me the solution for my issue

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to check duplicate records before Inserting

or

2.Each and every record in sqlite has rowid which is unique one. so delete the duplicate record

by using  rowid.

Comment: i want to check duplicate records before inserting